# SQL trying to use a column from a joined table in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I currently have which returns 3 columns for patient_id, group_concat_1, and group_concat_2:

```
SELECT patient_id,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM 
table1 where patient_id = patient.id
) group_concat_1,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM 
table2 where patient_id = patient.id
) group_concat_2
FROM patient
```

However, I need to return a single column with group_concat_1 and group_concat_2 combined, so I tried this:

```
SELECT patient_id,
SELECT CONCAT(group_concat_1, group_concat_2) FROM (
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM 
    table1 where patient_id = patient.id
    ) group_concat_1,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM 
    table2 where patient_id = patient.id
    ) group_concat_2 
)
FROM patient
```

But his clearly doesn't work since now it can't find patient.id in the inner subquery. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Theres nothing 'clearly' about it. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate directly the 2 columns:

```
SELECT p.patient_id,
  CONCAT(  
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM table1 where patient_id = p.patient.id),
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM table2 where patient_id = p.patient.id)
  )
FROM patient p
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want `concat_ws()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT patient_id,
       CONCAT_WS(','
                 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.column1) FROM table1 t1 where t1.patient_id = p.id
                 ),
                 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.column1) FROM table2 t2 where t2.patient_id = p.id
                 ) 
                ) as combined
FROM patient p;
```

There are two reasons:

1. You can distinguish between the last element from `table1` and the first from `table2.
2. If one of the tables has no matching values, this returns the results from the other.

Also note that I added table aliases and qualified column names.  This is quite important when working with queries that have multiple table references -- it helps prevent some very hard to debug errors.

I should add that your original query would run in most databases.  MySQL and Oracle happen to be two that don't understand nested correlation clauses.